# Are questions about eliminating parasites on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, asking-questions

I'm a mod on [Pets.SE](https://pets.stackexchange.com/) and we've got a new question [Eliminate Ancylostoma caninum from garden](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/31492/12501). Gardening and pest control are off-topic on Pets, so I'm wondering if this question would be accepted here. The help mentions plants and weeds exclusively, but OP is asking about eliminating hook worms (that infect a dog, but that's secondary) from a garden.

Any help is appreciated.

**Update**:

OP rephrased their question to make it more on topic at Pets and there is no longer a need to migrate the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My first impulse is to say off topic, as explained below, but I invite the community to chime in.

We have in the past for example accepted questions on mosquito control (with some prior discussion and controversy), but decided that they are just this side of the fence because it’s both a very common problem, affecting the way gardeners use their garden and it can be dealt with at least to a certain degree by gardening-related measures.

Dealing with a recurring parasite is a pets issue, because it requires knowledge about transmission channels and parasite biology, not gardening knowledge. We might be able to help with a very limited problem, e.g. how to change the ph level or  similar, but not with the overall issue.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it makes a lot of sense. I've already encouraged OP to edit their question to make it on-topic on Pets, but they haven't done so yet.

Answer (score 1):

While I'm at first inclined to say, no, it's not on-topic on G&L, the presence of hookworms in the soil could be a problem just as much as say, yellow jackets (and not just for pets). However, hookworms probably aren't something people usually think about in a gardening and landscaping context, since they don't typically interfere with gardening and landscaping (unless you don't like to wear shoes, or unless the dog is part of your landscape, in the same sense as a pond of fish). The hookworms are part of the landscape, though (much as heavy metals in the soil).

I'd say it would be okay to ask here, but it would be unusual, and potentially get close votes. I would think it would be *more* on-topic on the Pets network, especially since the focus of the question is the dog.

Your answer to the question demonstrates why it might be a better fit for the Pets network. That is, the problem might not be the soil at all, but the parasite lingering and reinfecting through things the medication didn't kill.

The bigger question seems to be about eliminating parasites generally, rather than this specific question. If it's about eliminating them from a non-landscape pet, I'd say no. If it's about eliminating them from the soil in order to protect a pet, I'd say it would be unusual, but slightly on-topic, and a better fit for the Pets network. If it's just to eliminate them from the soil without regard to a pet, I'd say it would be unusual, but on-topic.

If it's about removing parasites from plants, I'd say it's on-topic. Some plants even are parasites.